# How to fire a method in Lightning Web Component from Aura Template

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

Relatively new to Salesforce. I'm building a Community Pages site, and I built a custom template in a Lightning Component Bundle. I want to set an onclick event that works on the entire page area that fires a method on a LWC within the template. I found a tutorial that does almost exactly what I need:

https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/09/21/firing-a-method-in-lightning-web-component-from-parent-aura-component/

That works, but that relies on importing the LWC directly into the Aura component. I'm using {!v.body} in the template and using the Builder tool to drag LWCs into the body area of the template. So is there a way to target the LWC from the Aura parent, but the LWC that's been added in the builder to the {!v.body} area instead of directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `listener` inside your LWC component and fire a message from Aura. For this you can either use [LMS](https://sfwiseguys.wordpress.com/2020/08/10/lightning-message-service-implementation-examples/) or [window.dispatchEvent](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/delphi/js+dispatchevent)

Comment: Can you elaborate any? I've been trying to make window.dispatchEvent work with the LWC and parent Aura template and I've had no luck.

Comment: Can you please share your code so that i can check where exactly its going wrong.